# Standard definitions/schemas across developers for entities

Tags: standards, crm, data-modeling, data-warehouse, erp

Is there a standard or a de-facto standard recognized among developers for definitions/schemas in data systems?

Example: "username", often inconsistently referred to as "login", "nickname", "user", category/metadata "access data, personal data"; other ex: "retina scan", often inconsistently referred to as "retina scan", "iris scan", category/metadata "biometric data, access data".

Is there a standard that provides standard definitions/schemas for such terms?

Looking forward very much to your answers.

I have looked at ISO-11179 so far. However, this standard only provides guidance on how to define the terms, but no definitions themselves.

ISO-8000 is similar and for master data only.

Microsoft's Common Data Model provides definitions to a certain extent, but the CDM only covers a certain part of all possible definitions. Moreover, it is questionable how widespread it actually is. The Microsoft Open Data Initiative does not seem to have worked properly.

It is similar with schema.org.

I wonder if there is such a list of common definitions or each company ultimately creates their own definitions in their own systems (CRM / ERP / Whatever).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no global standard definition. There may be standards for specific industries, countries, ecosystems, etc but nothing that you could assume would always be accepted